# React Native: Draw on image with only JS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my app, after use selects an image from gallery, he needs to black out some part of it. for example draw a black line where there are some names or signatures.

Is it possible to achieve this with JS only? or do I have to make some native views separately for android/ios and implement it to react native?

or is there any image picker modules which provides such a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit late, but I think this library will do the trick:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas

You can load a picture beforehand as your canvas with the `localSourceImage`prop.

Comment: I am adding localSourceImage but it is now loading. Is it working now?